# Is there a way to make the for loop print the underscore in the same line not under eachother?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import random

list1 = ["chips", "banana", "cake", "wine", "cookie", "apple", "chocolate"]
random_word = random.choice(list1)
user_guesses = 0
guess_limit = 10
index = 0
guessleft = guess_limit - user_guesses
index_1 = random_word[index]
length = len(random_word)

for a in range(len(random_word)):
    print("_")
```

So the output of this loop will be underscores under eachother instead of them being after eachother like this _ _ _ _ _

How can i fix this?

Comment: use `print("-",end='')`, and then after the loop print a single newline by doing `print()`, although *in this particular case* you can just do `print("-"*len(random_word))`

Comment: in output u just only get _ _ _ because u not print the random_word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
print("_")
```

To this:

```
print("_", end="")
```

Or if you want them to have a space between them you can do it like this

```
print("_", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
for a in range(len(random_word)):
    print("_")
```

you can use

```
print(*('_' for i in range(len(random_word))), sep=' ')
```

or

```
print(' '.join('_' * len(random_word)))
```